# Unable to get Block by Height using Cosmpy module

Tags: blockchain, cosmos-blockchain

I am playing with Cosmos Blockchain and trying to get Block details inputting its height. For this purpose I am trying to use [CosmPy module.](https://github.com/fetchai/cosmpy)

[I found a function](https://github.com/fetchai/cosmpy/blob/de6dff15c0c83c5b4dae0ecf42b5bf5ec596239e/cosmpy/tendermint/interface.py#L71) inside the library that allows you to do exaclty what I want that is called

```
GetBlockByHeight()
```

But I am unable to use it since it require the block height (got it) and a self parameter (?) when I try to call it using:

```
from cosmpy.tendermint.interface import CosmosBaseTendermint
print(CosmosBaseTendermint.GetBlockByHeight(block_height))
```

What code should I use to properly call the function?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the working code:

```
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson
from cosmpy.common.rest_client import RestClient
from cosmpy.protos.cosmos.base.tendermint.v1beta1.query_pb2 import (
    GetBlockByHeightRequest,
    GetBlockByHeightResponse,
)
from cosmpy.tendermint.rest_client import CosmosBaseTendermintRestClient

rest_client = RestClient("https://rest-fetchhub.fetch.ai:443")
client = CosmosBaseTendermintRestClient(rest_client)
resp = client.GetBlockByHeight(GetBlockByHeightRequest(height=6000000))
print(MessageToJson(resp))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).